# How to assign to this sparse matrix with numpy indexing tricks instead of using loops?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have

- M: a floating-point sparse matrix (`csr_matrix` in scipy) of shape p*n, where p and n are about 1 million each.
- M': another floating-point sparse matrix of shape p'*n', where p' > p, and n'>n.
- IndexP: a vector of indexes, of shape 1*p with p unique unsigned integers no larger than p'
- IndexN: a vector of indexes, of shape 1*n with n unique unsigned integers no larger than n'

How can I transform the following loop into a fast sparse matrix array operation

```
for all i in range(n) and j in range (p) such that M[i,j]!=0:
   M'[IndexP[i], IndexN[j]]= M[i,j]
```

Example:

Assume

- M is

  [ [0 2]
  [3 0] ]
- IndexP is `[9,100]`
- IndexN is `[50,30]`
- M' is a sparse matrix such that `M'.shape=(200,200)`

Then the loop above will assign `M'[9,30]=2, M'[100, 50]=3` (and M' is 0 elsewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
M = np.array([ [0, 2], [3, 0] ])
IndexP = np.array([9,100])
IndexN = np.array([50,30])
idxn, idxp = np.where(M)
M2 =np.zeros((200,200))
M2[IndexP[idxp], IndexN[idxn]] = M[idxp, idxn]
```

Comment: Looks right to me!